# Instance refresh: "insufficient data to evaluate its health with Amazon EC2"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, healthcheck

The instance refreshes for my autoscaling group are taking a very long time due to instances having "insufficient data to evaluate its health with Amazon EC2."

However, the instances are passing EC2 health checks for 5+ minutes.

There is no other sort of health check, manual or load balancers.

What condition is the instance refresh *actually waiting on*? Is there any way to satisfy this condition faster, so that the instance refresh doesn't take so long?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Taking a shot in the dark, but check the "Health check grace period" setting.